Unable to cancel a condition
I don't know why the script cant cancel the close_conditiondown1 although I have already put the na.
ConditionDown1 = close[1] > close[2] and close < close[1]
var float Close_ConditionDown1 = na

if (ConditionDown1)
    Close_ConditionDown1 := close[1]
else if (close > Close_ConditionDown1)
    Close_ConditionDown1 := na

plot(Close_ConditionDown1, "Close_ConditionDown1", color=color.green)
plotshape(ConditionDown1, title="LowerHigh", location=location.abovebar, color=#ff525273,   style=shape.labelup, text="LH")

My intention is the script will cancel and start new when candle close higher than close_conditiondown1
